# How do exactly computers convert ASCII to Binary?

Tags: binary, ascii, machine-code

I have read that when you press a key on the keyboard, the OS will translate it to the corresponding ASCII, then the computer will convert ACII to Binary. But, what part of the computer converts ASCII to Binary? The question may be stupid because I have only started to learn CS.

Comment: Everything is binary in the computer. Characters are an illusion for human convenience.

Comment: What you read was wrong. When you press a key on the keyboard, a numeric keycode (value) is sent to the operating system or BIOS, and that numeric value is already binary (a series of bits that are either on or off). You're confusing what the computer sees and what the human using the computer sees - the computer only sees binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear with me, it has been a while since I dealt with this sort of thing...
When you press a key on the keyboard, a (very low) voltage signal is raised and is detected by one of the I/O subsystems on the motherboard - in this case the one responsible for the signals at the port that the keyboard is connected to (e.g. USB, DIN, Bluetooth, etc).

The I/O handler then signals this to the interrupt handler, which in turn sends it as a keyboard interrupt to the operating system's keyboard driver. The keyboard driver maps this high-priority interrupt signal to a binary value according to the hardware's specific rules. And this binary representation of the pressed key is the value that the operating system uses and/or hands over to another program (like a word processor, console/terminal, email, etc).

For example, and assuming a very simple, single-byte ASCII-based system (it gets a lot more complicated these days - UTF-8, UTF-16, EBCDIC, etc., etc.):

When you press the letters `g` and `H`, the two voltages get translated into binary values `01100111` and `01001000` respectively. But since the computer does not understand the concept of "letters", these binary values represent numbers instead (no problem for the computer). In decimal this would be `103` and `72` respectively.

So where do the actual letters come in? The ASCII code is a mapping between the binary representation, its numeric value (in dec, Hex, Oct, etc.) and a corresponding symbol. The symbols in this case being **g** and **H**, which the computer then "paints" on the screen. Letters, numbers, punctuation marks - they are all graphical representations of a number -- little images if you like.